# Route attribute not working in Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I recently changed my backend project from [WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend/) to [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server/). Within the 'new' project type it seems that the `RouteAttribute`, decorated on my controller methods are not working. Here is how the onfiguration looks like:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureMobile(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include;
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

What do I need that the `RouteAttribute` is working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an ordering issue. `config.MappHttpAttributeRoutes()` should be called before the MobileAppConfiguration is applied to the HttpConfiguration.

Comment: i run into similar issue but shifting the "MapHttpAttributeRoutes" before entire "UseDefaultConfiguration" block doesnt solve the problem